# Angular is not a known element: in same module

Tags: angular

I've a module in angular which holds two components.

The first component is defined as this.

**overview.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pricing-table',
  templateUrl: './pricing-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pricing-table.component.scss']
})
export class PricingTableComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

In the second component, I try to include the overview component using the given tag.

```
<app-pricing-table></app-pricing-table>
```

Both components are defined in the same module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [OverviewComponent, PricingTableComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SubscriptionRoutingModule,
  ],
})
export class SubscriptionModule { }
```

When I run `ng serve` I get an error. I`ve restarted the development server multiple times.

```
ERROR in src/app/modules/subscription/pages/overview/overview.component.html:13:1 - error NG8001: 'app-pricing-table' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-pricing-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-pricing-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

13 <app-pricing-table></app-pricing-table>

  src/app/modules/subscription/pages/overview/overview.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
    Error occurs in the template of component OverviewComponent.
```

What is wrong with my module/components?

**EDIT**

I'm lazy-loading the module in my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
{
   path: 'subscription',
   loadChildren: () => import('./modules/subscription/subscription-routing.module').then(m => m.SubscriptionRoutingModule),
}
```

and my `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CollapseModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'API_ENDPOINT', useValue: environment.apiEndpoint },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ApiEndpointInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: thats all you have in SubscriptionModule?

Comment: can you post the code of the OverviewComponent.html

Comment: Yes, not other import, exports, declarations or providers.

Comment: @Sajeetharan The overview html only containts the `<app-pricing-table></app-pricing-table>` tag.

Comment: have you imported the `SubscriptionModule` in your `AppModule`?

Comment: @OptimusPette No, it's lazy-loaded in my app-routing module.

Comment: post what you have on the `app-routing` module and `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "providers" to the lazy loaded SubscriptionRoutingModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [OverviewComponent, PricingTableComponent],
  ...
  providers: [OverviewComponent,PricingTableComponent]
})
export class SubscriptionRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you Marc! You made my day :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to export the components from the module which you have created and mention them in `exports:[ ]`

```
  exports: [
    OverviewComponent,
    PricingTableComponent,
  ]
```

Comment: I`ve added both components to the `exports` array, but still getting the same error. (Development server is restarted)

Comment: @Markus and then are you importing this module correctly in app.module.ts

Comment: I import it using lazy loading in the app routing `loadChildren: () => import('./modules/subscription/subscription-routing.module').then(m => m.SubscriptionRoutingModule),`